# Improved While Condition with || combination

Tags: while-loop, arduino

Two temperature  measurements (`temp_1`and `temp_2`) are taken. The temperature must not be `85` or `-127`.

One of 4 conditions have to be met for the while condition to keep on running. My working approach:

```
while (temp_1 == 85 || temp_1 == -127 || temp_2 == 85 || temp_2 == -127){
  // keep the while loop running
}
```

How could this while condition be shortened/improved? I've been trying things like:

```
while (temp_1 == 85,- 127 || temp_2 == 85,-127)
```

And it compiled but did not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always define a method or macro:

```
bool is_temperature_invalid(int temp) {
    return (temp == 85 || temp == -127);
}
```

and then use something like

```
while (is_temperature_invalid(temp_1) || is_temperature_invalid(temp_2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the first answer you could add in your entire conditional to the function:

```
// helper function for temperature validation
bool TempsValid (int temp_a, int temp_b){
    return temp_a == 85 || temp_a == -127 || temp_b == 85 || temp_b == -127;
}
```

A macro would go as follows:

```
#define TempsValid (temp_1 == 85 || temp_1 == -127 || temp_2 == 85 || temp_2 == -127)
```

Macro benefits can be that there is no function call. Speed/Storage-Usage if performance is an issue.

** warning on my #define

You can create macros that evaluate parameters like a function as well. This #define would fail to work if you changed the names of your variables.